# Why is my PHP not validating?

Tags: php, html, validation, preg-match

I am trying to make it so that if a person inputs the wrong postal code format or leaves the input null it will give an error. I am trying to figure out why it isn't working. Please help!

```
<td>Postal Code</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" value="<?php if($_POST['postal_code'] == null){  echo '';}else{echo $_POST['postal_code'];}?>"/>
</td>
<td class="error" colspan="2">
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['send_bulkform'])  && $_POST['postalcode'] != preg_match("[A\-Za\-z][0\-9][A\-Za\-z] [0\-9][A\-Za\-z][0\-9]",$_POST['postal_code']) || isset($_POST['send_studentform']) && $_POST['postalcode'] != preg_match("[A\-Za\-z][0\-9][A\-Za\-z] [0\-9][A\-Za\-z][0\-9]",$_POST['postal_code']))
        { 
            echo "Required, ex. A1A 1A1."; 
        }
        elseif(isset($_POST['send_bulkform'])  && $_POST['postalcode'] == null || isset($_POST['send_studentform']) && $_POST['postalcode'] == null)
        {
            echo "Required, ex. A1A 1A1."; 
        }
    ?>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: First of all, `preg_match()` and its colleagues require [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Secondly, there's no need to escape the dash in the character groups. Write `[A-Z]` instead of `[A\-Z]`.

Comment: BTW: It is probably not a good idea to validate postal codes at all, as there are  [too many formats in use around the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes). Some countries even use several formats.

Comment: What is that regex suppose to be doing? It would allow `A`, `-`, `Z`, `a`, `-`, or `z`. Then either `0`, `-`, or `9`.  Etc.

Comment: This is specifically for in Canada. 
    preg_match("{[A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z] [0-9][A-Za-z][0-9]}",$_POST['postal_code'])
Would something like this be better?

It is formatted to take a Canadian Postal Code.

Comment: ex. A1A 1A1, the outcome should be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect, and your PHP usage is incorrect. In PHP regexs need [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

A backslash in a PCRE regex escapes the next character. I would use:

```
[A-Z]\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d
```

and in PHP (add anchors so the whole string has to match):

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z]\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d$/', $string);
```

If the case is optional add either the `i` modifier after the delimiter:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z]\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d$/i', $string);
```

or add the lowercase character range as well:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z] \d[A-Za-z]\d$/', $string);
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cG9sG9/1
PHP Demo: https://eval.in/594444 (the 1 is true, for a match)

If the whitespace between the first grouping and second can vary use `\h` and either the `*` quantifier or the `+` quantifier. The `*` makes it not required (zero or more occurrences).

Comment: This was very helpful. I have not used Regex in PHP before and was just following what I read up on W3 schools and the PHP site. This makes so much more sense though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with this line:

```
if(isset($_POST['send_bulkform'])  && $_POST['postalcode'] != preg_match("[A\-Za\-z][0\-9][A\-Za\-z] [0\-9][A\-Za\-z][0\-9]",$_POST['postal_code']) || isset($_POST['send_studentform']) && $_POST['postalcode'] != preg_match("[A\-Za\-z][0\-9][A\-Za\-z] [0\-9][A\-Za\-z][0\-9]",$_POST['postal_code']))
```

1 - preg_match returns 1 for match or 0 for no match. So your test:

```
$_POST['postalcode'] != preg_match(...)
```

makes no sense and will most of the time be "true".
Just use:

```
 if(preg_match(...))
```

2 - Regexp inside preg_match is malformed. Replace:

```
preg_match("[A\-Za\-z][0\-9][A\-Za\-z] [0\-9][A\-Za\-z][0\-9]",$_POST['postal_code'])
```

with:

```
preg_match("/[A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z] [0-9][A-Za-z][0-9]/",$_POST['postal_code'])
```

Comment: You missed a `/` at the end of `preg_match` pattern.

Comment: thanks Daniel, you are correct, just edited my post.